# WCF Service Library in Isolation of Contracts

Tags: wcf, service, contracts

I want to write a WCF service library in separate  modules

1. one module(class library) for Contracts(IServices).
2. one module(class library) for Contract Implementations(Service).
3. one module(WCF service library by referring the above 2 modules) for
   configuring(hosting) the services. - It contains only app.config.

When I start to run the solution I am getting the following error.
"MetaData is missing"

In config file I specified the endpoint information in following manner

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyCompany.Framework.Services.ContractImplemenations.ProjectService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Services/ProjectService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyCompany.Framework.Services.Contracts.IProjectService">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Thanks,

Comment: You get the error when you are trying to consume the service or run the service?

Comment: Above error gone by deleting the Service.cs and IService.cs because I don't need them. After that While running I am getting the following error.---------------------------
Microsoft WCF Service Host
---------------------------
The target assembly contains no service types. You may need to adjust the Code Access Security policy of this assembly. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: So you're saying you deleted your service types to stop an error when consuming the service but now you're getting a different error saying the service contains no types? Go figure....

Comment: Are all 3 libraries (i.e., DLLs)?  If so then you need to write an application to host the service.  You can't execute DLLs, and the values you put in an app.config associated with a DLL will *not* be used.

Comment: @TomRedfern - Hi Tom, yes I deleted. If i have a service in that hosting WCF service library then I am able to test that in WCFClient. But if the service type is outside that project then I am not able to test that service

Comment: @Tim - Hi Tim, I know we will not able to work with dlls. My problem is In same service library if i've a TestService I am able to test that in WCF client or referring this service library in another client project. But if i move this service type to another library then I am not able to test this service

Comment: Please post your app config

Comment: I updated in the post. This app.config in "MyCompany.Framework.Services.ServiceHost", from here I referred to "MyCompany.Framework.Services.Contracts, "MyCompany.Framework.Services.ContractImplementations projects